# Is it possible to attach a shell to an existing ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, shell

I have a few `SSH tunnels` setup for auto-connection/re-connection with `Shimo`.

Is there a way of attaching shell access to those existing tunnels and how if so? Or will I have to establish a new ssh connection just for shell access?

Comment: What's the problem with just opening another connection?

Comment: No, no problem at all, I was just curious and got frustrated when google didn't shed any light on this. I've seen people attaching output of a process to a file while it was running so I was just wondering if something similar would be possible with ssh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is to to set `ControlMaster yes` in your initial connection.  Then you can connect additional sessions through the same connection, by connecting them to a control socket.  See ControlMaster in ssh_config(5) for details.